# Should Dockerfiles specify an entry point when using docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am migrating some web-apps to be managed via docker compose

It seems the docker-compose.yaml has a section for the container entry-point.

However, my individual docker files have an ENTRYPOINT themselves... should I remove this from the Dockerfiles? Does the entry-point in docker-compose override the Docker one?

Comment: docker-compose entrypoint overrides the docker image's entrypoint. You do not have to use the docker-compose entrypoint.

Comment: No and yes are the answers to the two questions. The exact term to use here is that you **may** define an entrypoint to override the default one (as you would do directly on the docker command of needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually shouldn't specify `entrypoint:` or `command:` in a Compose file.  Prefer specifying these in a Dockerfile.  The one big exception is if you have a container that can do multiple things (for example, it can be both a Web server and a queue worker, with the same code) and you need to tell it with a `command:` to do not-the-default thing.

I'd suggest a typical setup like:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    # with neither entrypoint: nor command:
```

```bash
# Dockerfile
FROM ...
WORKDIR /app
COPY ...
RUN ...

# ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint-wrapper.sh"]
CMD ["./my_app"]
```

Compose `entrypoint:` overrides the Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` and resets the `CMD`.  Compose `command:` overrides the Dockerfile `CMD`.

In the Dockerfile both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are optional.  If your base image already includes a correct command setup (`nginx`, `php:fpm`) then you can safely skip both.

It's otherwise somewhat a matter of style whether to use `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` in your Dockerfile.  I prefer `CMD` for two reasons: it's easier to replace in a `docker run ... image-name alternate command` invocation, and there's a pattern of using `ENTRYPOINT` as a wrapper script to do first-time setup and then launch the `CMD` with `exec "$@"`.  If you have a JSON-array-syntax `ENTRYPOINT` then you can pass additional command-line arguments to it as `docker run ... image-name --option`.  Both setups are commonplace.

The thing you shouldn't do is put an interpreter in `ENTRYPOINT` and a script name in `CMD`.  I only ever see this in Python, but `ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]` is wrong.  On the one hand this is hard to override in the same way `ENTRYPOINT` is in general, and on the other neither normal command override format works (you still have to repeat the script name if you want to run the same script with different options).